# Basic attribute table setup QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I made several point shapefile layers. The properties only differ in their assigned colours. Each attrubute table consists of a single field "id" and each record is null.

I now wish to assign a name (that the colour corresponds to) throughout each table. Can I do that in the id column, or is the id field something special that should be left alone? (I eventually plan to combine the tables then add other fields, I just want to start properly.)

Comment: The `id` column is just like any other column so you can fill it with values depending on its type (for example, it's quite common for `id` fields to be integer-type so you can't add strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate column and enter the value you want there. You can select all elements and enter the value directly in the second level of the toolbar.

Make you sure you name all columns you want to be merged the exact same.

Comment: To populate a field that is NULL throughout  with the same text in field calculator, I found that this works: CASE WHEN "field name" is NULL then 'some text' ELSE "field name" END works,